# How can I update a constructor parameter value in unity at run time

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have the following Unity configuration section

```
<register type="IDbContext" mapTo="ProjectEntities" name="ProjectEntitiesContext" >
          <constructor>
            <param name="connectionString" value="conString" />
          </constructor>
```

Which works great. I get the value of "conString" in the connectionString parameter of my ProjectEntities class.

However, what I would like to do is change the value of the conString parameter in code.

some thing like

```
   myIocContaniner.registratons.ProjectEntities.Constructor.value = "Different Connection String"
```

And have "Different Connection String" passed to the ProjectEntities constructor when its created.

The problem I am trying to solve is making a .net WebApi interact with different data bases based on the request.

Comment: Nope. You should use a factory that provides that value instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you resolve your IDbContext every time you use it (something like this)?

```
IDbContext myDbContext = myIocContainer.Resolve<IDbContext>("ProjectEntitiesContext");
// Some code here using myDbContext
```

You can just remap the type in Unity.

```
myIocContainer.RegisterType<IDbContext, ProjectEntities>("ProjectEntitiesContext", new InjectionConstructor("Different Connection String"));
```

The next time it resolves it, it'll be the new mapped type with the new injected constructor parameter.

This is also assuming you only have the connection string as a parameter to your constructor.  If you have other parameters, you'll need to adjust the InjectionConstructor accordingly.